# DataTables on click row doesn't work sometimes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I put a route as `data-href` attribute to table rows which I want to be linked to other pages (to edit for example). I register this as such:

```
$("table tbody").on('click', 'tr[data-href]', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("input"))
        return;

    window.location = $(this).data('href');
});
```

This works, but sometimes it doesn't. It looks like it has something to do with the speed that DataTables is being initialized. Sometimes it works fine, but then if I refresh it might not work, until refresh again. Hope anyone can help me out with this one. There are similar questions to this, but they're all solved by using the `.on('click', 'tr', function() {` method, which I already have applied.

Comment: If the problem might be caused by trying to add the click event before the table has finished being initialized, then you can try using the [`initComplete()`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option - and place your code in there. Otherwise, I think we would need a [mre].

Comment: Thanks @andrewjames I've put my javascript code in a function, and then called that function in the `initComplete()` option - this solved the issue!